# How do I add a title to a content control inserted from the XML Mapping Pane in Word?

Tags: ms-word, word-contentcontrol

How to insert Content Controls to a Word document from the XML Mapping Pane and have a title assigned to the inserted control?

My mapped XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TestXMLNode xmlns="abc">>
    <Subdivision>Subdivision</Subdivision>
    <Mileage>Mileage</Mileage>
    <Date>Date</Date>
</TestXMLNode>
```

This creates the following items on the XML Mapping window:

[image: XML Mapping window on Word]

When I right-click one of the items on that list I can insert the items as content control and it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to edit the XML file so that when the content control is inserted it already contains a title, like this:

[image]

I tried adding `title="Subdivision"` to the xml file but it did not work.

`<Subdivision title="Subdivision">Subdivision</Subdivision>`

Comment: I revisited the Mapping Pane, and as far as I can tell it *never* inserts a Content Control with a predefined Title. e.g. if you insert the "title" from core-properties namespace in the Mapping Pane the Content Control's Title is empty, whereas if you insert from the Insert->Document Property feature, Word assigns the title "Title" to the control. I think if it was possible to do this, Microsoft themselves would have done it, so suspect that it is not. (But a really good feature request IMO!)

Comment: ...So that means that you would have to find some other way to do what you want (possibly using any Word events related to the creation of new Content Controls).